# Capitalize View Column data - CRM2011

Tags: view, entity, dynamics-crm-2011

I am trying to customize a view of an entity in crm2011. The view contains a column named `Subject`. The requirement is that I have to customize this view so that the subject data should appear in Upper-Case. Is it possible? If so please give me some helpful links as I am out of clues here.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really something CRM supports out of the box, but I can think of a two of ways to do this:

1. Create another field, which contains a copy of the subject, but always in upper-case, have a plugin or workflow activity maintain this. Then just show that column in your view, instead of the original subject column.
2. You will probably be able to add a plugin to the retrieve multiple message, this will be fired as someone looks as at the view, then you can alter the results (e.g. upper case the subject column) - I havn't done this myself but I have been told its possible.

Comment: re: (2) I have done this (albeit in CRM 4.0) and there are some things to consider. Firstly there are cases when the `Execute` message is used instead of the `RetrieveMultiple` message so you may need to write a plug-in that handles both messages (sorry, I can't remember what scenario used Execute). Secondly, registering plugin on the `RetrieveMultiple` or `Execute` messages are both "expensive" as these messages are called a lot. +1

Answer (score 1):

If the `Subject` can always be capitalized, you could add some simple javascript to the  update event of the field that capitalizes its contents.

Of course you'd need some method to go through and capitalize everything that already exists.  (easily done with a command line app using the XRM SDK).